# How to parse ZonedDateTime with milliseconds

Tags: java, jodatime, jira-rest-api, zoneddatetime, localdatetime

Jira is giving me this date format via Rest API:
`2021-01-21T11:08:45.000+0100`

How can i parse this to a `LocalDateTime` in Java?

I tried

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-01-21T11:08:45.000+0100", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

Or this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-01-21T11:08:45.000+0100"), formatter);
```

The result is `DateTimeParseException`

Comment: Your string contains a UTC offset (`+0100`) , not a time zone. So unless you have very specific requirements, prefer to parse into an `OffsetDateTime`, not a `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot parse String in ISO 8601 format, lacking colon in offset, to Java 8 Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360852/cannot-parse-string-in-iso-8601-format-lacking-colon-in-offset-to-java-8-date)

Comment: Or does this? [Parse date string without losing timezone in Groovy for Jira](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948091/parse-date-string-without-losing-timezone-in-groovy-for-jira). I figure it should be straightforward to translate the code from [the answer by daggett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53948810/5772882) to Java.

Comment: Thank you @OleV.V. Your second comment does the trick. Nevertheless i had to use the given formatter of that link. So both solutions work, your suggestion and the selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the zone offset in your value is in the format `+0100`, it cannot be parsed with any of the predefined formatters like `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, as it expects it to be in the format `+01:00`

You can parse `2021-01-21T11:08:45.000+0100` with the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-01-21T11:08:45.000+0100", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
```

The reference for `DateTimeFormatter` is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: It works. Thank you very much - also for your link and explanation